# Deleting features with date attribute before today's date using ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-rest-api

I have a published feature service where road closure information is input to be shared with the public. The data input contains a couple of project date fields. I'd like to use a script that runs on a schedule on the server machine to automatically delete records before today's date. It looks like the way to properly do this is to use ESRI's ArcGIS REST API. We are running ArcGIS Server 10.1.

The date field is DISCONTINUEDATE.

I've worked out a query and it looks like I'd to delete all records WHERE:

```
DISCONTINUEDATE < SYSDATE
```

I'm brand new to the REST API and just not sure about the code to set up a delete using the above query.